# ansible with_sequence result message hide

Tags: ansible

I want to hide the result message of `with_sequence`:

My task playbook  :

```
 - name: Alarm check
      debug: msg="Alarm check"
      when: '"{{ item }} alarms currently active" in HOST_MGMT1.stdout'
      register: result_alarm
      with_sequence: start=0 end=10
```

**result output message:**

```
##########_QFX10K_##########
Current time: 2020-03-13 11:34:58 KST
{All items completed', 'changed': False, 'results': [{'item': u'0', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}, {'item': u'1', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}, {'item': u'2', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}, {Alarm check', 'item': u'3', 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'failed': False}, {'item': u'4', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}, {'item': u'5', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}, {'item': u'6', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}, {'item': u'7', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}, {'item': u'8', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}, {'item': u'9', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}, {'item': u'10', 'skipped': True, 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', 'changed': False, 'skip_reason': u'Conditional result was False'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [skippy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/skippy.html#skippy-ansible-screen-output-that-ignores-skipped-status) callback [plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#callback-plugins). For example the playbook

```
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    HOST_MGMT1:
      stdout: "3 alarms currently active"
  tasks:
    - name: Alarm check
      debug: msg="Alarm check"
      when: "my_item in HOST_MGMT1.stdout"
      register: result_alarm
      with_sequence: start=0 end=10
      vars:
        my_item: "{{ item }} alarms currently active"
```

gives (abbridged)

```
shell> export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=skippy
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***

TASK [Alarm check] ***
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) => {
    "msg": "Alarm check"
}

PLAY RECAP ***
localhost: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```